# html table with horizontal and vertical scrolling and fixed headers AND fixed column widths

Tags: html, scroll, html-table, fixed

I have an HTML table that I'd like to have

1. vertical scrolling
2. horizontal scrolling
3. fixed headers (that do not vertical scroll, but do horizontal scroll)
4. fixed column widths - i.e. fixed table layout
5. ideally, fixed first column (like freeze panes)

My research indicates that you can't do this in pure CSS because the typical strategy is to create a header div for the headings and then another div for the table data, and then use jQuery/javascript to synchronize the scrolling of the header/table data.

I've tried a few plug-ins, and actually did a deep dive into these two

http://fixedheadertable.com/

http://www.novasoftware.com/Download/jQuery_FixedTable/JQuery_FixedTable.aspx

However, these plug-ins don't work for me because I need/prefer to have fixed column widths as opposed to auto-resizing ones.

If anybody has a solution to my problem or can recommend how to modify the plug-ins for fixed width, it would be greatly appreciated!

Hopefully I'm not asking for too much!

Answer (score 2):

I think the nova jquery fixedtable is just ok, its Features are:

- Allow horizontal and vertical scroll
- Support multiple HTML tables with fixed header and columns on one page
- The number of fixed columns can be customize
- The background colors of each row when mouse is over and out can be customized

anyway, why not ask their developers.
http://www.novasoftware.com/contactus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was presented with the same problem and came up with a lightweight solution to your problem. What I did was:
The solution for my issue was to do this in buildFixedTable:
Replaced `var th = $(1*).appendTo(target);`
With `var th = $(2*).appendTo(target);`

And added `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` to the grid definition
And made a protected void handler for this where I set the column widths.

Voila!

```
1* = (lt)table(gt)(lt)/table(gt)
2* = (lt)table(gt)(lt)col style=width:20%(gt)(lt)col style=width:20%(gt)(lt)col style=width:60%(gt)(lt)/table(gt)
```

Where

`lt` = Less_than_sign
`gt` = Greater_than_sign

Might require some testing for your implementation, but it solved my issue ...